# django+nginx+uwsig return 500

Tags: django, nginx, http-status-code-404, uwsgi

I am using nginx+uwsgi to deploy my django app,everything is ok when I use django's self server,but when I use nginx+uwsgi,it will return 500 or 404 and diplay my custom 500 or 404 page.

I define the "static_root" in django setting and run "python collectstatic", the static file seems work well.

my uwsgi ini file:

```
[uwsgi]                                                                                                                         │·
project = api_security                                                                                                          │·
base = /var/wd/App                                                                                                              │·
                                                                                                                                │·
chdir = %(base)/%(project)                                                                                                      │·
# home = %(base)/Env/%(project)                                                                                                 │·
module = %(project).wsgi:application                                                                                            │·
                                                                                                                                │·
master = true                                                                                                                   │·
processes = 5                                                                                                                   │·
                                                                                                                                │·
# socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock                                                                                   │·
socket = 127.0.0.1:8081                                                                                                         │·
chmod-socket = 664                                                                                                              │·
chown-socket = www:www                                                                                                          │·
vacuum = true                                                                                                                   │·
daemonize=/var/log/uwsgi/api_sec.log
```

my nginx config file:

```
# configuration of the server                                                                                                   │·
server {                                                                                                                        │·
    listen      10080;                                                                                                          │·
    server_name 10.213.11.54;                                                                                                   │·
    charset     utf-8;                                                                                                          │·
                                                                                                                                │·
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/api_sec.access.log;                                                                              │·
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/api_sec.error.log debug;                                                                          │·
                                                                                                                                │·
    client_max_body_size 75M;                                                                                                   │·
                                                                                                                                │·
    location /static {                                                                                                          │·
        alias /var/wd/App/api_security/run/static;                                                                              │·
    }                                                                                                                           │·
                                                                                                                                │·
    location / {                                                                                                                │·
        # uwsgi_pass  django;                                                                                                   │·
        # include    /usr/local/nginx/nginx/conf/uwsgi_params;                                                                  │·
        include         uwsgi_params;                                                                                           │·
        uwsgi_pass     127.0.0.1:8081;                                                                                          │·
    }
```

I use this config file in my other project,it works well, but in the project which access multiple ddatabase, it will display 404 or 500.

I see the error log of nginx and uwsgi, but I still have no idea about this question,I am stucked...

Comment: `uwisgi` socket will have 660 mode, if `nginx` workers are not running as the same user (or at least group) as `uwsgi` workers the OS will stop you because of permissions.  What do you set `user` to in `nginx.conf` and what groups that user belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

You should post the uWSGI error log to know what is the cause of your server error 500. Usually you have an error or exception there that should point you to the source of the error.

Here you can find a step by step guide on how to deploy Django, NGINX and uWSGI:
https://www.guguweb.com/2019/11/13/django-nginx-deploy-your-django-project-on-a-production-server/